# Displaying the circuit diagram associated to a circuit in Q#+Python

Tags: programming, q#

I am learning the Q# language, and my script is in Python (I am using the online Azure interface).

I created an example quantum circuit on three qubits:

```
%%qsharp

    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Arrays;
    
    operation AlgoTest() : Result[] {
        use q = Qubit[3];
        mutable resultArray = [Zero, size = 3];
        CNOT(q[1],q[0]);
        H(q[2]);
        H(q[0]);
        S(q[1]);
        I(q[2]);
        CNOT(q[2],q[1]);
        H(q[2]);
        for i in IndexRange(q) {
                    set resultArray w/= i <- M(q[i]);
                }
        return resultArray;
    }
```

**Is there a simple way to represent the quantum circuit associated to AlgoTest in a standard quantum circuit diagram?**

I found these refs ([1](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/tree/main/samples/runtime/qpic-simulator), [2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/qsharp/quantum-viz-js-a-quantum-circuits-visualization-library/)), but they seem to assume the full program is in Q# (while I am using Python+Q#). For instance the command:

```
%%qsharp
%trace AlgoTest
```

Doesn't return me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%trace` magic only works in notebooks with Q# kernel (not Python+Q#), and only if they run on a local Jupyter Notebooks setup, not in Azure-hosted notebooks. There's no way to get a circuit plotted when running the code in Azure.

[qpic sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/tree/main/samples/runtime/qpic-simulator) can be a viable workaround, but it also requires a local setup and it also assumes that the quantum circuit is expressed in Q#.

Comment: Allright, thank you. As I see you work for Microsoft, I should say it would be a useful functionnality in the Aazure workspace =)